# App name is not showing when doing email verfication in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Let Suppose My app name is `FavApp` in my firebase console I maked project named `FavApp`

but when I am doing `Authentication` Works then my app name is not showing.

**When doing email verification**

example of how it's look -

[image]

As you can see in this image my app name is `FavApp` and it is showing `project-153288687373`
so guys you can also feel it is not looking good. so instead of `project-153288687373` I want to show this name `FavApp` how can I do that in Firebase console or Google Cloud Console.

#### for your information in Firebase > Authentication > Templates > Email address verification -

[image]

here you can see `%APP_NAME%` but still not showing

Answer (score 3):

The &APP_NAME% field in the email authentication template refers to your public facing project name. Your current public facing project name is project-153288687373.
To update this name, in the firebase console, select your project, navigate to project settings, and under the 'General' tab, you'll see a field to update this value.

Comment: I will try thank you for your answer I will let you know when It's work today I am busy so maybe not able to check this but I think this will work thank you.

Comment: To clarify for anybody this might help, it is not the "Project name". At the bottom there is a Public settings section, and the field is "Public-facing name".